# Is it possible to use Android AudioRecord class to record audio which is outside human hearing frequency?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I know that we can use [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class in Android to record audio. My question is, is it possible to record audio which is outside human hearing frequency using this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the frequency that can be captured, is a function of the cellphone microphone as opposed to the Android implementation of recording audio. I would suggest that you find the spec of the microphone in the phone that you are looking at and then look at its [frequency response diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone#Measurements_and_specifications) to find out the exact frequencies it can capture.

Moreover, I think it should be possible to capture things like dog-whistles over a normal microphone(not sure about cell phone mics). Reference: http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=5478

> Most dynamic mics roll off their frequency response around 15 to 16
>   kHz, and condenser microphones around 18 to 20 kHz.